# GitHub gh-pages site returns 404 for specific file

Tags: github, github-pages

My Repository: https://github.com/aleha84/simple.canvas.core2/tree/gh-pages

I regularly update the "gh-pages" branch to see the result, but the last time for the file with the name "infoScreenScene.js" (https://aleha84.github.io/simple.canvas.core2/demo8/Scenes/infoScreenScene.js) I get response - 404.
The file in the branch is present - https://github.com/aleha84/simple.canvas.core2/blob/gh-pages/demo8/scenes/infoScreenScene.js

Added **.nojekyll** file to repository root, but it did not help. Is there any specific ignore rules? I know only about "vendor" and "_" prefixes.

Comment: You used `Scene` instead of `scene` in your URL.

Comment: I did not know that the case of letters is checked in the whole path, and not only in a file name